# For Each <ul>, Count <li> tags and create elements based on that number

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through each UL on my page, count the number of list items in each ul, and then add a new list item into the ol tag for each list item in each section. So for the first section's ol tag there should be three list items created, and for the second section, there should be four list items created.

The page I'm working on will have an undetermined number of sections with varying numbers of list items in each. The best I've been able to do so far is have 7 list items (the total number for the entire page) get added to each ol tag.

```
<section>
<ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ol><!--Add new list items Here-->
</ol>
</section>
<section>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ol><!--Add new list items Here-->
</ol>
</section>
```

Here's what I've got right now:

```
var $sections = $('section')

for (i = 0; i < $sections.length; ++i) {
    var $ol = $.find('ol');
    var $items = $.find('ul li');
}
$($items).each(function(){
    $($ol).append("<li><a href='#'>Element Created</a></li>");
});
```

I'd also like to set each href of the list item created equal to it's own index. Meaning the end result should look like:

```
<section>
<ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li><a href='0'>Element Created</a></li>
    <li><a href='1'>Element Created</a></li>
    <li><a href='2'>Element Created</a></li>
</ol>
</section>
<section>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li><a href='0'>Element Created</a></li>
    <li><a href='1'>Element Created</a></li>
    <li><a href='2'>Element Created</a></li>
    <li><a href='3'>Element Created</a></li>
</ol>
</section>
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: You realise that the `href` of the first three items in both created `<ol>` elements will point to the same place? Is that what you want?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, that is what I want. The HTML above isn't a true representation of what I'm actually doing, just a simplified version that strips out everything that wasn't relevant to my problem. I can definitely see where that would seem an odd thing to do without understanding what I'm using href index value for. Thank you for your answer and the JS Fiddle Example!

Comment: You're very welcome, I can only hope it was of some use :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate trough the ul elements via `each`. In the callback, `this` refers to the respective ul, and you can count the elements inside of it

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).children('li').size() );
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this).children('li').size(); i++) { 
     $(this).next('ol').append("<li><a href='" + i + "'>Element Created</a></li>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul').each(function(){
   var olElement = $(this).next('ol');
   $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
        var elementCopy = $(this).clone().attr('href',index);
        olElement.append(elementCopy);
   });
});
```

What this does is:

1. Find every ul element on page.
2. Find its sibling "ol" element.
3. Iterate through every "li" element child of ul.
4. Makes "href" attribute of the new 'li' object the INDEX of an object. (or do whatever else you need via index)
5. Copy this child into a sibling "ol".

Answer (score 2):

My own approach to this problem would be:

```
// Select 'ul' elements, iterate over them using 'each()' method:
$('ul').each(function(){
    // we'd be using $(this) twice, so we're caching for a slight
    // performance benefit:
    var $this = $(this);

    // finding the 'ol' nextSibling, setting its HTML to the HTML of the
    // current 'ul' element:
    $this.next('ol').html($this.html())
    // finding the 'li' elements:
    .find('li')
    // iterating over those, using 'each()':
    .each(function(i,el){
    // i: the index of the current 'li' in the collection,
    // el: the current Node (effectively the 'this' node).
       // creating a new 'a' element, setting its properties:
        $('<a />', {
            'href' : '#' + i,
            'title' : 'Link to: ' + i,
            'text' : 'Element created'
        // replacing the current childNodes of 'el', with the created
        // element:
        }).replaceAll(el.childNodes);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3UZDd/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
  - [`replaceAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/).